# CAShapeLayer(layer) move one place to another place using Gesture in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, layer

Here bellow my code I want move shapeLayer(layer) using gesture.

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let ellipsePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(100, 200, width , height))
shapeLayer.path = ellipsePath.CGPath
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
shapeLayer.sublayers?.removeAll()
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

I am using bellow touch function for identify layer but did not work.

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let point = (touches.first! as UITouch).locationInView(self.view) // Where you pressed
        if let layer = self.view.layer.hitTest(point) as? CAShapeLayer { // If you hit a layer and if its a Shapelayer
            if CGPathContainsPoint(layer.path, nil, point, false) { // Optional, if you are inside its content path
                print("Hit shapeLayer") // Do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use shapelayer inside a small custom View to detect touches in that view and proceed as you want.